# Result of putting a screen to the right of a diverging lens

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

I understand that when you ray trace for a diverging lens, a virtual image forms. See diagram below attached below. I also understand that you cannot capture this virtual image on a screen, as explained in this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/578229/why-cant-virtual-images-form-on-a-screen). But what would happen if you place a screen to the right of the lens. Rays still come out of the lens, so light would still hit the screen. Would the screen be rays of light that don't match the arrow object shape?

[image: Ray tracing diverging lens.].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtual vs Real image](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2658/)

Comment: @BioPhysicist From the attached link, it seems that if you place a screen to the right of a diverging lens, you'll just get a haze of light since no image converges. Is this the correct interpretation?