# What happens when screen is not placed where Image is focused but elsewhere?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, geometric-optics, thought-experiment, optical-materials

When we try to form a real image on a screen by a convex lens, we place the screen at a distance where the image is focused. But if we try to place the screen at a distance less than the distance where the image is focused(refracted rays still fall on the screen) so will the image appear on the screen or will screen be blank? If image does appear how will we calculate its magnification and position?

Comment: [This answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/578242/156895) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image will not be sharp if the screen is not too much of the right place, but you still recognize it, if it is too far away, the image will be so blurred, that it does not seem an image.

Comment: Will we be able to calculate the height of the image in such a case?

Comment: Yes even with a blurred picture you have  b/g=B/G b the distance of B from the lense, g the distance of the object, G it's size and B size of picture